Divisibility by 2015 of a number with alternating digits without modular arithmetic
Some time ago a friend came to me with the following problem, taken from a German math magazine (he doesn't have the full reference):

Find the smallest number that is divisible by 2015 and that consists of only two alternating digits.

While I could solve the problem using modular arithmetic (I sketch my solution below), my friend seems to remember that the solution in the magazine involved complex numbers and roots of unity. My guess is that it has something to do with generating functions, but I'm not sure what to look for, since generating the sequence of multiples of 2015 or the sequence of numbers $\overline{BA}, \overline{BABA}, \dots $ (or $\overline{A}, \overline{ABA}, \dots $) doesn't look very helpful. Even the solutions to older MSE questions I could find about similar problems (e.g., this or this other) use approaches similar to mine and have nothing to do with complex numbers.
Does anyone have any idea of how this problem can be solved using complex numbers? Or any other approach not based on modular arithmetic?
Sketch of my solution
The number we are looking for is one of
\begin{align}
Z_n &= \overline{A\underbrace{BA\cdots BA}_{2n}}= A\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n}10^{2k} + B \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^{2k+1} && A\in\{1,2,\dots,9\}, B\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\} \\
Z_n' &= \overline{\underbrace{BA\cdots BA}_{2n}}= A\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^{2k} + B \cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}10^{2k+1} && A\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}, B\in\{1,2,\dots,9\}
\end{align}
Next, we know that $2015 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 31$ and we can study the divisibility of $Z_n$ and $Z_n'$ by the three prime factors. Focusing on $Z_n$, it is quite straightforward to show the following.

$Z_n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ implies $A=5$.
$Z_n \equiv 4(9^n-1) + 5 + 11 B(9^n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$ implies $B=8$ if $n\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $B=0$ if $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.
$Z_n \equiv 11(7^n-1)+5+12 B(7^n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{31} \iff (11+12B)(7^n-1) \equiv 26 \pmod{31}$.

From the last two points, one easily gets that either $(A,B)=(5,8)$ and $n\equiv 10 \pmod{15}$ or $(A,B)=(5,0)$ and $n\equiv 14 \pmod{15}$.
A similar analysis shows that the numbers $Z_n'$ are divisible by 2015 as long as $A\in\{0,5\}$, $\forall B\in\{1,2,\dots,9\}$, and $n\equiv 0 \pmod{15}$.
In summary, the smallest number with alternating digits divisible by 2015 is
$$
Z_{10} = 5\underbrace{85\cdots 85}_{20 \text{ digits}} = 585,858,585,858,585,858,585 = 2,015 \times 290,748,677,845,452,039.
$$

Does that work?  See this  I believe I got your number right, but of course I might have misunderstood it.

Hi lulu! No, I meant 20 digits in total, not 20 pairs. I will write the entire number in the post, so it's clearer.

Got it.  Yes, I think that all works.
